# Django. Difficult queryset

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have user like this:

```
{
"name": "test"
"parent_users": [
       1,
       2
    ]
}
```

I need to display the user `"name": "test"` two times becouse he has two parents, for example i need to display the user `"name": "test"` like this:

```
{
"name": "test"
"parent_user": 1
}
{
"name": "test"
 "parent_user": 2
}
```

My serializer

```
class CommitmentListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id',
                  'email',
                  'first_name',
                  'last_name',
                  'parent_user',)
```

I cant understand how i can to create quesryset for this

***UPD***

user model

```
class User(PermissionsMixin):

        id = models.CharField(primary_key=True,
                              unique=True,
                              max_length=128,
                              default=uuid.uuid4,
                              editable=False)

        email = models.EmailField(
            _('email address'),
            max_length=100,
            unique=True,
            null=True,
            blank=True,
            default=None,
            error_messages={'unique': _("A user with that email already exists.")}
        )

    ...
# another fields
    ...
    parent_user = models.ManyToManyField('self',
                                             unique=False,
                                             symmetrical=False,
                                             blank=True)

...
```

Comment: can you please share the model structure?

Comment: @ruddra i have added the model